# App engine CPU times when downloading logs

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

The log messages in the log viewer in the admin console look like this:

> 1.2.3.4 - - [13/Nov/2010:06:16:33 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2121 "http://referrer.example.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; .NET CLR 2.0.50727),gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)" "www.example.com" **ms=30 cpu_ms=167 api_cpu_ms=120 cpm_usd=0.004975**

However when I use the following to download my request logs:

```
appcfg.py --num_days=0 --include_vhost request_logs appdir requests.txt
```

What is written to the file looks like this:

> 1.2.3.4 - - [13/Nov/2010:06:16:33 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2121 "http://referrer.example.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; .NET CLR 2.0.50727),gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)" "www.example.com"

Is there a way to download that missing timing information with my logs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--include_all` flag too.

```
appcfg.py --num_days=0 --include_vhost --include_all request_logs . requests.txt
```

**edit**:

If you would also like to download the logging messages, use `--severity=0`.

```
appcfg.py --num_days=0 --include_vhost --severity=0 --include_all request_logs . requests.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! I found that using `--severity=0` only downloads requests which logged a message. So I make two calls, one without `--severity=0` (to get all requests), and one with (to get requests with their logging messages).

Comment: Actually the difference is a little more subtle than that, if you include `--severity=0` it downloads *application* logs.  Without `--severity=0` downloads the request logs.  So, there are actually "*duplicates*" between the two logs.  Matthew Blain has started writing a tool to parse the log downloads into an sqlite database  It has some important limitations at the moment, but may still be useful: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/a8ec10b5f376920f?fwc=2&pli=1

Comment: Seems that --include_all is not available - I checked in the documentation and tried with the java command line but it didn't work. Any idea what happened to it? thanks.

Comment: @Li It is (still) in the Python version: `appcfg.py help request_logs [...] --include_all         Include everything in log messages.`