# Google app engine request_logs command line --include_all option is not available

Tags: google-app-engine, command-line-arguments

I saw this link - [App engine CPU times when downloading logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196646/app-engine-cpu-times-when-downloading-logs) that refers to a question about how to get the performance information when downloading logs from google app engine with **--include_all** option.

I've tried it with the Java command line options and read the documetnation and it is not mentioned there at all!

How can I get the performance infromation such as cpu time when I download the logs from app engine?
The command I'm currently using (it works) is:

```
appcfg.cmd --num_days=3 --severity=0 request_logs . logs.txt
```

In the admin dashboard you can see this information:

```
"<my_app_name>.appspot.com" ms=13 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000102
```

I want to be able to get this information in the logs as well.

thanks,

Li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java version of appcfg doesn't currently support that flag. You can create an app.yaml and use the Python version of the SDK to download the logs, though.